# IEnumerable con C#

Tags: c#, lista

Quisiera saber como corregir el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Evita las imágenes de código por favor. Es preferible que copies y pegues el código y el mensaje de error. Lee [Te he votado negativamente porque una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/)

Comment: OK, en la proxima lo copio y lo pego

Answer (score 5):

El error es absolutamente descriptivo. La definición de tu `IEnumerable` no puede estar directamente dentro del `namespace`, debe estar dentro de un clase. Mueve la definición dentro de la clase `Juego`.